# Angular cannot read property 'Version' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

I'm had quite a hard time installing angular2 and setting it up locally using `Babel` and `Webpack` to reimplement a simple `Hello world` app in angular components, just to get started.

I'm currently having this runtime error:

`index.html:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Version' of undefined` if you are curious.

Here's a sexy image illustrating the situation.
[image: Error Image]

I tried to figure out where this error occured and it turns out it's angular (correct me if I'm wrong).

This line to be exact, `var VERSION=new _angular_core.Version(\"2.4.8\") ...`.

Can I get some help please ? Thanks !!

---

#### app.component.js

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Hello Angular 2</h1>
    `
}) export class AppComponent {};
```

#### app.module.js

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
}) export class AppModule {};
```

#### main.js

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

#### index.js

```
require('!!script-loader!@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.min.js');
require('!!script-loader!@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.min.js');
require('!!script-loader!@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.min.js');
require('!!script-loader!@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js');
require('!!script-loader!rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js');
require('./main')
```

Comment: it means that there's nothing called `new _angular_core`, could you please share more codes ? how do you think we could know what is it really 
`var VERSION=new _angular_core.Version(\"2.4.8\")` ??

Comment: @5313M Done, sorry for not providing the code from the start. Thanks

Comment: can you share your code in plunker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your angular packages should be at the same version. Which means core common compiler etc. should all be 2.4.8.

The problem is that I think before 2.2 or 2.3 of Angular this get version didn't exist. So if you have lets say `@angular/core` at 2.2 and `@angular/common` at 2.4.8 then `@angular/common` might use features of `@angular/core` which don't exist in that older version of `@angular/core` yet like for example maybe `angular.core.getVersion()`

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you could start your first projects using Angular CLI. It saves you the trouble of having to set up an entire development environment. A decent setup is provided by the Angular team. You can install it using by running 'npm install -g @angular/cli'.

You can then create a new project with the command 'ng new PROJECT_NAME' and run it with the command 'ng serve'. That's really all there is to it :-) Have a look at the docs to get you up and running here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

When you feel confident about your project and wish to get your hands dirty with the build configs (based on webpack!), use the 'ng eject' command.

Comment: I would strongly advise against using Angular CLI as a complete beginner. Before using a tool like this, you should first understand what the CLI is doing. Follow some tutorials (the official Tour of Heroes is good) and try to understand what each feature does and why they are required.

Comment: This is a great answer and it completely solves my problem but doesn't actually answer the question. I do not want to use `typescript` and all the dependencies that come along with it, I had enough of chasing bugs. thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

To get angular's version:

```
import * as angular2 from 'angular2/angular2';
console.log(angular2.version);
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1357